# Scrollview not displaying images

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a chat like widget that is able to display both text and images. I want to be able to dynamically add data, as data is coming in over time. I decided do go with a scroll view and use a grid layout, and overtime add instances of labels and images. The problem is, the images are not rendered. I think it may be due to their size, but I'm not quite sure if that's the case, and if so, how to fix it.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image


Builder.load_string('''
<SV>:
    do_scroll_x: False

    GridLayout:
        id: layout
        cols: 1
        spacing: 10
        size_hint_y: None
''')


class SV(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(30):
            if i % 3 == 0: self.add_iamge('1.jpg')
            else: self.add_label(str(i))


    def add_label(self, text):
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(Label(text=text))

    def add_iamge(self, src):
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(Image(source=src))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

And this is what it renders
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question - Label's height

> how can I determine the minimum height the label needs in order to be
>   rendered correctly?

## Solution

Use either one of the following:

### Snippets - kv file

```
# Label’s size will be set to the text content (plus padding):
<Label>:
    size: self.texture_size
```

or

```
# Label that can grow vertically but wraps the text at a certain width
<Label>:
    text_size: root.width, None
    size: self.texture_size
```

### Snippets - Py file

```
def add_label(self, text):
    self.ids.layout.add_widget(Label(text=text))
```

## Solution - ScrollView not displaying images

The following enhancements are required.

- Set the size of the `ScrollView` e.g. `size_hint: 1, None` and `size: (Window.width, Window.height)`
- Make sure the `height` is such that there is something to scroll e.g. `height: self.minimum_height`
- When adding a widget, one needs to provide the `size` of the widget e.g. `size_hint_y=None, height=40`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image

Builder.load_string('''
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<SV>:
    do_scroll_x: False
    size_hint: 1, None
    size: (Window.width, Window.height)

    GridLayout:
        id: layout
        cols: 1
        spacing: 10
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

''')


class SV(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(30):
            if i % 3 == 0:
                self.add_iamge('raspberrypi.png')
            else:
                self.add_label(str(i))

    def add_label(self, text):
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(Label(text=text, size_hint_y=None, height=40))

    def add_iamge(self, src):
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(Image(source=src, size_hint_y=None, height=40))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to just about solve the problem. Only one thing, I wanted to make the images and labels have different heights. I think I can manage with the images by using the ratio and setting a minimum and maximum height and interpolating between according to the ratio to get the maximum height, but when it comes to the labels, how can I determine the minimum height the label needs in order to be rendered correctly? Thanks!